# Existential definitions in ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

In formal set theory (ZFC to be specific) there are some types of definitions: predicate definitions, for instance $A \subset B$ is an abbreviation of $\forall x(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B)$, comprehension definitions, for instance $A \cap B$ is an abreviation of  $\{x \in A: x \in B\}$

The predicate definitions are abbreviations of formulas and 
comprehension definitions are abbreviations of sets  (terms or objects in ZFC).

The problem is with existential uniqueness definitions where we put a name to an object which existential uniqueness is given by a theorem of existential uniqueness. Let be the theorem of existential uniqueness $\forall x \exists! y (\forall z (z \in y \Longleftrightarrow z \subset x))$. It is a direct consequence of the Power Set Axiom.

In this case given a set A, the Power Set Pow(A) is not an abbreviation, you can not substitute Pow(A) by $\forall x \exists! y (\forall z (z \in y \Longleftrightarrow z \subset x))$ because one is a Set (a term or object) and the other is a formula. How can this type of definitions be expressed in a formal way?

Even worse, in many books the Power Set Axiom $\forall x \exists y (\forall z (z \in y \Longleftrightarrow z \subset x))$ is used directly to name Pow(A) without mention that the uniqueness must be proved in order to be able to define Pow(A).

I used Pow(A) as an example but my question is about existential definitions (Is this the right name for this type of definitions?) in general for ZFC. Where a can I find a proper treatment of this topic?

Briefly "existential definitions" are essentially different to definitions such that:

$A \subset B   \equiv_{def}
 \forall x(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B)$

$A \cap B \equiv_{def}
   \{x \in A: x \in B\}$

How a existential definition can be written?
It is unavoidable the use of metalanguage?

How to name an object that exists thanks to an existential uniqueness theorem?

Comment: As a footnote on Asaf's answer, if we denote "the unique $x$ such that $\varphi$" as $\imath x \varphi$, we can't treat this as an abbreviation in any helpful way without adding new terms to the language. But terms never occur on their own, only as parts of formulae, so if you think instead of how to unpack $\imath x\varphi\in A$ or $A\in\imath x\varphi$, it's easier to treat these as abbreviations of formulae in the language of set theory with only $A$ free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you specify a condition, uniqueness follows by extensionality. And since that we *can* prove that, there is little point in using $\exists!y$ in the statement of the axiom, because $\exists!$ is not a standard quantifier, but rather a shorthand statement for a much more complicated formula.

Now, you want to talk about class-functions like $\mathcal P(\cdot)$ or constants like $\varnothing$ or $\omega$. And that is a valid concern, since the language of set theory only has the $\in$ symbol.

Enter the notion of a conservative extension. In logic, if you have a language $\cal L$ and a theory $T$, and you have a formula $\varphi(x)$ such that $T$ proves that $\varphi(x)$ defines a unique set, then we can extend the language to $\cal L^+$ by adding a constant symbol $c_\varphi$ and the axiom $\varphi(c_\varphi)$.

We can now prove that any model of $T$ can be interpreted naturally as a model for $T+\varphi(c_\varphi)$ as an interpretation for the language $\cal L^+$. Similarly we can do that with definable functions or relations. And moreover, every proof from $T+\varphi(c_\varphi)$ in $\cal L^+$ can be translated to a proof from $T$ in the language $\cal L$.

And that is what actually going on. In effect we extend the language of set theory to include many "convenient symbols", and we know that we can recursively translate all the statements and proofs from the extended language back to the original language of set theory with just $\in$.

Comment: Thank you, Asaf but I was expecting a solution more syntactical than the semantical way using model theory used in your answer. It is hard to me understand. I was expecting more in the direction of the Malice's comment.

Comment: This *is* a syntactic way, I just dressed it up as a semantic way since I like to think about semantics more than I do about syntax. The point is that you can recursively unpack the extended definitions so that every *proof* (syntactic object) in the extended language is translated to a proof in the original language.

Comment: Right, I need to think more in a syntactical way because in the ZFC version I am working on, model theory can't be used. Each quantifier has its own and explicit universe that may be different each time you write a quantifier.

Comment: The point is that this is really just what you'd expect. There is no "clever tricks" here. You just replace each formula where the "extended function" appear by claiming there exists some object which satisfies this and that; the uniqueness, again, is not necessary since we already know that ZFC proves the uniqueness of these things.

Comment: What do you mean by "extended function"? May be a formula in the way appear in the replacement axiom where it does not mention the word function but the functional relation is present in the formula.

Comment: You have the extended language of set theory $\in$ and $\mathcal P$, where $\mathcal P$ is the power-set operator. Take ZFC as it would be defined in this language (i.e., add the necessary axioms to Replacement as well), then every proof can be recursively translated to a proof from ZFC in the language of $\in$. And in this translation we also don't need to require every time that the $y$ which instantiates as the power set of $x$ is unique, since ZFC already proves that.

Comment: Ok Asaf, you have explained clearly that introducing a new symbol doesn't affect the language at all, by starting "You have the extended language of set theory ∈ and P, where P is the power-set operator. Take ZFC as it would be defined in this language". However, the core of my question is: How it can be defined in the language? (I would now add syntactically).

Comment: Then I don't understand the "core of your question". The power set operator is defined as $\varphi_P(x,y)$ is the formula $\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow\forall u(u\in z\rightarrow u\in x))$ (note that $\subseteq$ is ***not*** part of the language of set theory, so formally it is also an abbreviation). Now if you want to say something about power sets, then you say that $\exists y(\varphi_p(x,y)\land\psi(y))$. Other than that, it might be a good idea to take initiative and find a reasonable logic book which covers the notion of "conservative extensions" and read more about that.

Comment: I stress in my question that definition such as:

Comment: Such as what? If the power set operator is just an example, I don't see why is my answer not general enough "just" for using the same example. We are starting to go in circles, and I fear that without proper clarification on your side, I don't see a point in continuing this.

Comment: How do you know y exist in order your operator makes sense? The answer is the power axiom. My question is how to name the object y that exist for each set x, thanks to the power axiom? In many textbooks, this is done loosely. How to name an object that exists thanks to an existential uniqueness theorem?

Comment: @CarlosFreites: I'm not sure what you mean by "name".  Each time you want to refer to such an object, you use a bound variable for it which you require to satisfy the defining condition.

Comment: I mean name outside the formula. Suppose I have a uniqueness existential formula $\exists! y(\varphi(y,x))$ (theorem XYZ) Now I want to refer to the set the formula says it is unique. In textbooks, this is done more or less as "Let be NEW(x) the set the theorem XYZ says it is unique given a set x." Then, from that moment on, $\varphi(NEW(x),x)$ it is assumed as true.

Comment: The last comment was to @EricWofsey.

Comment: @CarlosFreites : but it's actually the same as for $A\cap B$: the theorem $\forall A\forall B\exists C (\forall x, x\in C\iff (x\in A\land x\in B))$ is a theorem, and from this you can use $A\cap B$ as being $C$. It's no different, since $\{x\in A : x\in B\}$ is also used in the metalanguage only : it can't be a term since there are formulas in it

Comment: @Max: $\{x\in A : x\in B\}$ is a set (so a term) thanks to the comprehension axiom. The problem we are dealing with here is precisely how to connect symbols such as \{x\in A : x\in B\} and POW(x) with existential uniqueness theorems.

Comment: @Carlos: Formally speaking, $\{x\in A: x\in B\}$ is not a term. It uses the informal curly-braces operator, which is---if nothing else---a second order operator. The comprehension axiom allows you to prove that for all $A$ and for all $B$ there exists $C$ such that $x\in C\leftrightarrow x\in A\land x\in B$; and extensionality allows you to prove that this $C$ is actually unique. Now whenever you want to refer to this $C$ you need to start by stating that "There exists $C$ such that $C$ is the such and such set ..." and then whenever you write $C$ you mean $A\cap B$ for the rest of the proof.

Comment: @Carlos : unless you're using a very weird definition of term, a term cannot use a formula in its formation. There are no terms in the (usual) first order theory ZF, except for variables

Comment: @Max That is true! Thanks for making me realize that there are no terms in ZFC. I have assumed implicitly that almost things such as ${\emptyset}$ where terms of ZFC. Very interesting and useful for me.

Comment: Huh. I was sure that my second paragraph addressed that. Apparently not clearly enough.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some uncertainty as to precisely what you're asking, but perhaps this is an answer to your question.

If you want to only use abbreviations of the sort used for $A\subset B$, the answer is that you don't try to translate terms in isolation; you try to translate formulas in which they occur. Since the well formed formulae of set theory are formed inductively from atomic formulae of the form $\alpha\in\beta$ and $\alpha=\beta$, that means if we want to "translate $\{x:\varphi\}$" you just have to figure out what "$\{x:\varphi\}\in\alpha$," "$\alpha\in\{x:\varphi\}$," and "$\alpha=\{x:\varphi\}$" should be abbreviations for. Here is a version that works adequately in ZF:

- For $\alpha\in\{x:\varphi\}$, we can just say it's a synonym for $\exists y(\alpha\in y\wedge\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow\phi))$.
- For $\{x:\varphi\}\in\alpha$, we say that this is just short for $\exists y(y\in\alpha\wedge y=\{x:\varphi\})$.
- and for $\alpha=\{x:\varphi\}$ we refer to the first bullet point and extensionality, translating it as $\forall y(y\in\alpha\leftrightarrow y\in\{x:\varphi\})$.

If we keep unpacking any formula containing set abstracts in this way, we'll eventually reduce them to formulas in which the only terms are variables and the atomic formula are those involving $\in$ and $=$. These formulae get really long and ugly, though; luckily, for reasons Asaf gives, we don't really have to be careful about this as long as our axioms guarantee the existence of a set of all the things satisfying the property $\varphi$--we can just treat them as atomic terms and carry on.

Comment: The one in the first bullet is the only one genuine because it is the only one that allows getting rid of the symbol $\{x:\varphi\}$. The other two bullets need the first one as you noted. That is a good description on how to get rid of a symbol as $\{x:\varphi\}$. The question is: How the symbol $\{x:\varphi\}$ is introduced? This case is especially hard because it comes not from an axiom but axiom scheme.

Answer (score 3):

In the language of ZFC there are no constants or functional symbols, so the only terms are variables. One way how to deal with defintions is to ignore the possibility to introduce new symbols and just imagine that every formula that uses definitions is an abbreviation of a formula in language of ZFC. Definitions can be regarded as an informal but precise way how to write shorter and more readable formulas in the place of very long ones. It should be clear how to translate a formula containing defined symbols into a formula in the pure ZFC language.

For example, $A\subset B$ can be translated into $(\forall x)(x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B)$, and a formula containing $\subset$ somewhere inside is translated by replacing appropriately each subformula of the form $A\subset B$. Similarly for any defined predicate symbol $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

As regards defined function symbols, all we need is to know how to translate a formula of the form $y=F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, this is replaced by the formula $\varphi(y,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ used as a definition of $F$. Then we also know how to translate $y\in F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$: we replace it by $(\exists z)(y\in z\wedge\varphi(z,x_1,\dots,x_n))$. Similarly we can translate $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in y$. The fact that for any $x_1,\dots,x_n$ there is exactly one $y$ satisfying $\varphi(y,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ can be regarded as a "background knowledge", there is no need to encode it directly into the translation.

By the way, $\{x\in A\!:x\in B\}$ is also an abbreviation which has to be translated into a pure ZFC language; formula $y=\{x\in A\!:x\in B\}$ is of course replaced by $(\forall x)(x\in y\Leftrightarrow(x\in A\wedge x\in B))$.

Comment: No, that's inaccurate. There is a formalized way of introducing new symbols. It's exactly what I was talking about in my answer, conservative extensions; specifically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservativity_theorem is relevant in this case.

Comment: Maybe what I wanted to say was: "One way how to deal with defintions is to ignore the possibility to introduce new symbols and just imagine that every formula that uses definitions is an abbreviation of a formula in language of ZFC". Anyway, thank you for the comment.

Comment: Yes, that is what we often do, we look at all these things as abbreviations. But that's easier to do with relations (e.g. $A\subseteq B$) than it is with terms (e.g. $\varnothing$ or $A\times B$).

Comment: @PeterElias Would be nice you change the phrase in your answer "Also, there is no formalized way for introducing new symbols." by the one in your last comment. Your answer is the type I am looking for.

Comment: @Asaf About your last comment. Exactly!

Comment: @Carlos: As I keep saying, conservative extensions by adding new function symbols.

Comment: @CarlosFreites Done... I am glad you like my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your comments to Asaf's answer, I think another way to solve your issue would be with another viewpoint : think in terms of (classical) sequent calculus.

Assume you want to prove the theorem "For any set $A$, there exists $B$ such that there is an injection $A\to B$, and no surjection $A\to B$". The usual choice to prove this theorem is using $B=P(A)$. But how to write this formally ?

When you do your sequents calculus, at some point you arrive at $ZF\vdash \exists B, \phi_P(A,B)$ where $\phi_P(x,y)$ is an abbreviation for the formula "$y$ is the powerset of $x$".

At this point you think "Let $B$ be the powerset of $A$", and your natural deduction proof goes on with $ZF, \phi_P(A,B)\vdash ...$" where "..." is anything it must be.

When you arrive at "$ZF, \phi_P(A,B)\vdash$  there is an injection $A\to B$ and no surjection $A\to B$",  you can use one of the inference rules of the sequent calculus :

From $\Gamma, \phi(t)\vdash \psi$ ($t$ not free in $\Gamma$) and $\Gamma \vdash \exists x, \phi(x)$, infer $\Gamma\vdash \psi$.

Apply this to $\phi(x) = \phi_P(A,x)$, and $\psi = \exists y, \Omega(y)$ where $\exists B, \Omega(B)$ is the formula we're trying to prove, you finally get $ZF\vdash \exists B, \Omega(B)$. Using generalization, $ZF\vdash \forall A, \exists B, blabla$.

So we've used the powerset of $A$ in a formal proof, but the thing is you can name it (store it in a sense) as a nonused variable, by putting its definition on the side of the hypotheses, and using the (now used) variable in the proof, using its definition at various points in the proof.

That's if you want to use the defined object to prove something else. If you want to prove some properties of the defined object, there are similar things you can do, for instance instead of proving $\forall A, |P(A)|>|A|$ you can prove $\forall A, \forall B, \phi_P(A,B)\implies |B|>|A|$ etc. Since there is only one $B$ such that $\phi_P(A,B)$, this last theorem is the same thing as what you're trying to prove.

I've done this in a purely syntactical fashion but of course to my mind it's important to keep in mind the semantic aspect of things, and in this regard, Asaf's answer mentioning conservative extensions is a very interesting one. Note that he also mentioned the syntactic aspect ("translating a proof in $\mathcal{L}^+$ into a proof in $\mathcal{L}$ recursively"), the only thing I did "more" is give hints as to how this translation can be achieved.

If anyone can make my answer better by correcting some mistakes I've probably made, such modifications are of course most welcome

Comment: I corrected the $\rm\LaTeX$ :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach that fx Bourbaki uses is introducing the [Hilbert operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_calculus). By doing that you don't need more primitives as the quantifier(s) can be expressed in therms of the Hilbert operator.

The advantage of using this is that the language allows a construct to turn a predicate into an object (fulfilling the predicate if possible).

This is similar to the ad-hoc solution to simply allow definition of a symbol by a predicate that has unique validity.